# Using PHP to Display Data in a Morris Chart

Tags: javascript, php, morris.js

I am trying to use php to display data in a morris bar chart in the code below:

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: [
        { <?php echo $graphData[0]; ?> },
        { <?php echo $graphData[1]; ?> },
        { <?php echo $graphData[2]; ?> },
        { <?php echo $graphData[3]; ?> },
        { <?php echo $graphData[4]; ?> },
        { <?php echo $graphData[5]; ?> },
        { <?php echo $graphData[6]; ?> }
    ],
    xkey: 'y',
    stacked: true,
    ykeys: ['Spotify ','Apple '],
    labels: ['Spotify ','Apple ']
    });
```

The problem is that when I copy and paste the echoed string directly in the data field such as this -> y: 'Feb', 'Spotify ':9.99, the graph displays the data. However, when I allow the php to echo this string into the data field like in the code above, the graph doesn't display the data. Not sure why. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: are you using PHP inside of your JS file?? or is the javascript code inside of the php file along with HTML and everything??    why don't you check the source code loaded when you open the page in the browser (using F12 key), is the source code what you expected??

Comment: It is in a php file with HTML and everything. Thanks for the tip of checking the source code in the browser. Still new to web development and that really helped.

Comment: i'm glad it helped!! did you solve your problem??   sometimes the sourcode view helps you  catch some "  or '  in there that you missed in your coding but is messing everything up...

Comment: Yes, I was able to solve the problem once I saw how it was printing out on the page. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you can create array of data in php and then convert array to json
and use json in javascript:

```
    $data = [
    [ 'year'=> '2008', 'value'=> 20 ],
    [ 'year'=> '2009', 'value'=> 10 ],
    [ 'year'=> '2010', 'value'=> 5 ],
    [ 'year'=> '2011', 'value'=> 5 ], 
    [ 'year'=> '2012', 'value'=> 20 ]
  ];

$jsonForUseInJavascript = json_encode($data);
```

and then in javascript echo json and parse it to array:

```
Morris.Bar({
    element: 'bar-example',
    data: JSON.parse('<?php echo $jsonForUseInJavascript ?>'),
xkey: 'y',
    stacked: true,
    ykeys: ['Spotify ','Apple '],
    labels: ['Spotify ','Apple ']
});
```